# Power Apps DataVerse Import Mapping Issue

Tags: powerapps, dataverse, powerapps-modeldriven

I am working on a table and want to import data from Excel. The problem I am running into is that I delete a column from the table, click "save". I wait for a minute and then to import that data and the deleted column is still showing up in the Column mapping list. If I go to edit data in the table, the column does not show up.

Am I missing something? If I have to do something special to get it to stick, please let me know. This is super frustrating!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably metadata is cached and it’s not published completely.

There are [two ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/create-edit-fields) to do customization changes in Dataverse - one classic way in Dynamics CRM solution explorer & a brand new maker portal experience.

If you face any such issues, switch to classic in action bar and do Publish All customizations there. That will force the metadata changes to take effect. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/create-edit-field-solution-explorer#edit-a-column)

The save button should do the same in new maker portal and if needed try to refresh the import mapping screen to start fresh :)